# Load classes in runtime after classloader loads it from other jar file AspectJ

Tags: aspectj

I have a programm - `app.jar` and my lib.

My lib attachs to `app.jar` with `-javaagent:...`.

My `aop.xml`:

```xml
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.ua.aspectj.ChameleonAspectLogger"/>
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="com.ua.aspectj.*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

In `app` programm own `ClassLoader`. After `app` launched, he load other classes from jars (load plugins).

If i tell aspectj use classes from plugin, he will not find them and write about this in log.

How i can tell aspectj that he must use loaded classes?

There is no possibility compile all plugins in one jar and put in every plugin `aop.xml`

Comment: Please show your code. You will not receive any meaningful answer without people being able to reproduce your problem. Your prose description is quite abstract.

Comment: @kriegaex my code contains `aop.xml` and one aspect. what to show? `app` i can't show because it compiled. People can reproduce with `app`, but i can't give it.

Comment: What to show? I already told you: your code, both aspect and application code, a simple demo application reproducing the problem. There is no code (also no aspect as you falsely claim), no error message, only a bare config file. Feel free to help yourself if you cannot support the people who want to solve your problem for you.

Comment: @kriegaex I can't show you demop application because: 1. it works only from specified `IP` address. 2. I do not have sources, just compiled `.jar` file. 3. I can not disclose and to whom either give the programs and data of the firm in which I work. 
Aspect code I will show on Monday.

Comment: @kriegaex The point is not in the code, but in the possibility as such

Comment: I think we just misunderstand each other. When I said demo application, I meant an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not the original software. With AOP the point is always a combination of application code, aspect code and configuration because without all three there is no way to reproduce problem. Please just provide a little example causing the same problem as your original code, because from your unclear explanation I have no clue what "the possibility as such" even means. This discussion is taking too long already, like I need to convince and beg to you to let me help you.